# python ssh in to a jumpserver and then ssh in to a host from the jumpserver to execute a command

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I want SSH to a jumpserver. From the jumpserver, I want SSH to a host and execute a command: 'rpm -qa | grep package' and get the output. Once done, I want successfully logout of the host first and then logout of the jump server.

Below is what I have tried thus far:

```
Import pexpect

options = '-q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oPubkeyAuthentication=no'

child = pexpect.spawn('ssh ssheth@jumpserver %s'%(options), timeout=None)
child.expect(['password: '])
child.sendline('hello123')
child.expect('#')
child.sendline('ssh ssheth@host "rpm -qa | grep -v watch | grep extractor"')
child.expect(['password: '])
child.sendline(password)
child.logfile = fout
child.expect(".*\$ ", timeout=None)
child.close()
```

This throws the below exception:

```
Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().
<pexpect.spawn object at 0x7f007800d190>
version: 2.4 ($Revision: 516 $)
command: /usr/bin/ssh
args: ['/usr/bin/ssh', 'ssheth@jumpserver', '-q', '-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null', '-oPubkeyAuthentication=no']
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile("#")
buffer (last 100 chars): ssheth@jumpserver:~[ssheth@jumpserver ~]$ 
[ssheth@jumpserver ~]$ 
before (last 100 chars): ssheth@jumpserver:~[ssheth@jumpserver ~]$ 
[ssheth@jumpserver ~]$ 
after: <class 'pexpect.TIMEOUT'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 27286
child_fd: 91
closed: False
timeout: 2
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest answer is to open a port forwarding to the remote server.

This works best in bash, but you can subprocess, or whatever you prefer to run it through python.

Suppose the IPs are:

- jumpserver IP is 151.121.121.121
- finalserver IP is 10.1.2.3

Like follows

```
# Open a local port 13000 that will map through jumpserver and 
# connect to finalserver on port 22
ssh -L 13000:10.1.2.3:22 username@151.121.121.121
# Then open an ssh session to localhost:13000 (which will forward to the
# finalserver.com and run your command)
ssh username@localhost -p 13000 'rpm -qa | grep package'
```

Aside: looking at your expect script and remembering the old days. Python has some ssh wrappers. [Paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko) is used with [Fabric](https://github.com/fabric/fabric).

Comment: Unfortunately, the hostname/IP for the finalserver can not be resolved when I use local port forwarding since it is only available for access through the jump server.

Comment: @ssheth, sorry, the last SSH line was wrong :(. Fixed, now, it should make sense.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I appreciate your answer - thanks for that. Works like a charm. 
Here are the steps followed based on your reply:
Step 1:
ssh -L 13000:172.31.15.22:22 ssheth@jumpserver
Step 2:
$ ssh ssheth@localhost -p 13000

The other way I thought about was to enable public key based authentication on the final host from the jump server and simply run the below command:
ssh ssheth@jumpserver "ssh ssheth@finalhost 'rpm -qa | grep -v watch | grep extractor; exit'"

Comment: Great. sometimes the :13000 works, sometimes -p is needed. I'll update with the -p. The next thing you might check out to simplify is the ~/.ssh/config file, `man ssh_config` for details. You can specify all of these there, and type 'ssh remote_server' or whatever you want to label it.

Comment: @Jonathan - I am in similar situation but with one extra thing to do. I want to transfer a file from local to jumpserver and then from jumpserver to main server. 
I am getting similar error during SCPing file from jumpserver to main-server. 
Your solution will solve the SSH part but what should I do about SCP? Any leads please.

Comment: scp uses -P for the port specification. hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding. 
Can you please have a look at my question ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851964/transfer-filescp-and-run-command-from-jumpserver-to-finalserver-using-python-s

Answer (score 1):

You can install [jumpssh pypi](https://pypi.org/project/jumpssh/) using `pip`

```
pip install jumpssh
```