# Transfer file(scp) and run command from jumpserver to finalserver using python script on localhost

Tags: python, ssh, scp, pexpect

A file needs to be uploaded to final-server and a command needs to be run using that file as input.

Following will be the steps for whole action to be performed (but I am stuck at step 3):

1 - transfer file from localhost to jumpserver (using scp)

2 - ssh to jumpserver

3 - transfer file from jumpserver to finalserver (using scp)

4 - ssh to finalserver

5 - run the command on finalserver (with file as input)

```
try:
    cmd_str = "scp " + file_path + " " + user + "@" + jumpbox + ":/tmp/"
    print "---------local to jumpbox initiated:"
    #print cmd_str

    child = pexpect.spawn(cmd_str) #-------------------------------------------------------step 1
    child.expect("password:")
    #pwd = raw_input("please enter password along with yubikey:")
    pwd = getpass.getpass("Enter password along with yubikey:")
    child.sendline(pwd)
    i = child.expect(['Permission denied', filename])
    if i==0:
        print "Permission denied on host. Can't login"
        pwd = getpass.getpass("Enter password along with yubikey:")
        child.sendline(pwd)
        #child.kill(0)
    elif i==1:
        print "file successfully transferred to jumpbox"

        #----SSHing into jumpbox
        ssh_jump_cmd = "ssh " + user + "@" + jumpbox 
        print ssh_jump_cmd
        ssh_child = pexpect.spawn(ssh_jump_cmd) #-------------------------------------------------------step 2
        ssh_child.expect("password:")
        pwd2 = getpass.getpass("Enter password along with yubikey:")
        ssh_child.sendline(pwd2)
        i2 = ssh_child.expect(['Permission denied', '[#\$]'])
        if i2 == 0:
            print "Permission denied on host. Can't login. Try again"
            pwd2 = getpass.getpass("Enter password along with yubikey:")
            ssh_child.sendline(pwd2)
        elif i2 == 1:
            print "--------------Inside Jumpbox:"

            #sending file from jumpbox to finalserver
            ba_cmd = "scp /tmp/"+ filename + " " + cmd_var + ":/tmp/"
            print ba_cmd
            ba_child = pexpect.spawn(ba_cmd) #-------------------------------------------------------step 3
            ba_child.expect("Enter passphrase for key:")
            phrase = getpass.getpass("Enter passphrase: ")
            ba_child.sendline(phrase)
            print "Password should be asked:"
            i3 = ba_child.expect(['Enter passphrase for key', 'Permission denied', filename])
            if i3 == 0: 
                phrase = getpass.getpass("Enter passphrase: ")
                ba_child.sendline(phrase)
            elif i3 == 1:
                print "Lost connection:"
                ba_child.kill(0)
            elif i3 == 2: 
                ssh_ba_cmd = "ssh " + smba
                ba_ssh_child = pexpect.spawn(ssh_ba_cmd) #-------------------------------------------------------step 4
                ba_ssh_child.expect("Enter passphrase for key: ")
                phrase = getpass.getpass("Enter passphrase: ")
                ba_ssh_child.sendline(phrase)
                i4 = ba_ssh_child.expect(['Permission denied', '[#\$]'])
                if i4 == 0:
                    print "Passphrase incorrect. Exiting"
                    ba_ssh_child.kill(0)

                elif i4 == 1:
                    final_cmd = "ls -l" + filename #- just an example for this question
                    final_child = pexpect.spawn(final_cmd)
                    print "********************"
                    print sys.stdout
```

I spawn child using Python `Pexpect` and got successful till SSHing to jumpserver. When script tries to SCP from jumpserver to finalserver, following error gets generated :

```
scp /tmp/filename finalserver:/tmp/
End Of File (EOF). Exception style platform.
<pexpect.spawn object at 0x7efddfdad650>
version: 3.1
command: /usr/bin/scp
args: ['/usr/bin/scp', 'filename', 'finalserver:/tmp/']
searcher: <pexpect.searcher_re object at 0x7efddfdad5d0>
buffer (last 100 chars): ''
before (last 100 chars): 'ssh: Could not resolve hostname finalserver: Name or service not known\r\r\nlost connection\r\n'
after: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: 1
flag_eof: True
pid: 7244
child_fd: 5
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
```

I went through `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913540/python-ssh-in-to-a-jumpserver-and-then-ssh-in-to-a-host-from-the-jumpserver-to-e` but still need help.

TIA.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, isn't it? The name `finalserver` does not resolve.

Comment: Jumpserver knows what finalserver is but as I am running the script from localhost, it is not able to resolve finalserver. There's where I am stuck. How to proceed now ?

Comment: Why are you spawning the command locally? Feed it to the jumpserver child.

Comment: After sshing into jump, i should fire command using Popen over there. 
Is that what you mean. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>    ba_child = pexpect.spawn(ba_cmd)
```

You are spawning a new local child.  You should instead be sending the `scp` command to the `ssh_child` which is running a shell on the jumpserver.

Shaky on the syntax here, but something like

```
ssh_child.sendline(ba_cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to transfer files between server and execute commands with paramiko, just look at example

```
import paramiko 
local_path = "foo/bar"
remote_path = "bar/foo"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("remote_url", username='username')
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
ssh.exec_command('mkdir -p '+ remote_path)
sftp.put(local_path, remote_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time and commenting. I would have tried Paramiko but my query is solved. It was just a small tweak I was doing wrong. :-)